# Can `clean` and `clean_fieldname` methods be used together in Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, modelform

I am trying to implement registration with email and phone on a website. A user can register with either phone or email or both. If a user keeps both phone and email field empty, a `ValidationError` is raised, "You cannot leave both phone and email fields blank. You must fill at least one of the fields."

We have separate `clean` methods for `username, email, phone, password`. I do not want to implement the above-mentioned validation on `save()`. I don't want to define a `clean` method in the User model, either.
I have written tests for this form, and they pass. But what errors could possibly arise if I use both `clean` and `clean_fieldname` together? Could it become a problem when working with views?

I have 3 questions:

1. **Can I use both `clean_fieldname` and `clean` methods in a
   form?**
2. In what other way can I make sure that user registers with at least
   phone or email?
3. How do `clean()` and `validate()` works? I have read django documentation, but I don't understand it completely.

Here's the code I implemented.

```
class RegisterForm(SanitizeFieldsForm, forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    message = _("Phone must have format: +9999999999. Upto 15 digits allowed."
                " Do not include hyphen or blank spaces in between, at the"
                " beginning or at the end.")
    phone = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+(?:[0-9]?){6,14}[0-9]$',
                             error_messages={'invalid': message},
                             required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    MIN_LENGTH = 10

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password',
                  'full_name']

    class Media:
        js = ('js/sanitize.js', )

    def clean(self):
        super(RegisterForm, self).clean()

        email = self.data.get('email')
        phone = self.data.get('phone')

        if (not phone) and (not email):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("You cannot leave both phone and email empty."
                  " Signup with either phone or email or both."))

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.data.get('username')
        check_username_case_insensitive(username)
        if username.lower() in settings.CADASTA_INVALID_ENTITY_NAMES:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Username cannot be “add” or “new”."))
        return username

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.data.get('password')
        validate_password(password)
        errors = []

        email = self.data.get('email')
        if email:
            email = email.split('@')
            if email[0].casefold() in password.casefold():
                errors.append(_("Passwords cannot contain your email."))

        username = self.data.get('username')
        if len(username) and username.casefold() in password.casefold():
            errors.append(
                _("The password is too similar to the username."))

        phone = self.data.get('phone')
        if phone:
            if phone_validator(phone):
                phone = str(parse_phone(phone).national_number)
                if phone in password:
                    errors.append(_("Passwords cannot contain your phone."))

        if errors:
            raise forms.ValidationError(errors)

        return password

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.data.get('email')
        if email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _("Another user with this email already exists"))
        return email

    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.data.get('phone')
        if phone:
            if User.objects.filter(phone=phone).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _("Another user with this phone already exists"))
        return phone

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot out of reading the Django code; it is a well-commented codebase! The relevant section is in [django/forms/forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L362). When a form is cleaned/validated, it will call `full_clean`. This will first call `_clean_fields`, which calls the field `clean` and looks for a `clean_{fieldname}` method on the form to call. Then, the form `clean` is called.

```
def full_clean(self):
    """
    Clean all of self.data and populate self._errors and self.cleaned_data.
    """
    self._errors = ErrorDict()
    if not self.is_bound:  # Stop further processing.
        return
    self.cleaned_data = {}
    # If the form is permitted to be empty, and none of the form data has
    # changed from the initial data, short circuit any validation.
    if self.empty_permitted and not self.has_changed():
        return

    self._clean_fields()
    self._clean_form()
    self._post_clean()

def _clean_fields(self):
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        # value_from_datadict() gets the data from the data dictionaries.
        # Each widget type knows how to retrieve its own data, because some
        # widgets split data over several HTML fields.
        if field.disabled:
            value = self.get_initial_for_field(field, name)
        else:
            value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
        try:
            if isinstance(field, FileField):
                initial = self.get_initial_for_field(field, name)
                value = field.clean(value, initial)
            else:
                value = field.clean(value)
            self.cleaned_data[name] = value
            if hasattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name):
                value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
                self.cleaned_data[name] = value
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.add_error(name, e)

def _clean_form(self):
    try:
        cleaned_data = self.clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        self.add_error(None, e)
    else:
        if cleaned_data is not None:
            self.cleaned_data = cleaned_data
```

Comment: Actually, the [validators documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/) explains this order explicitly too.